# PHP How to display a from mysql with dynamic column

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

[This is DB Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVtMT.jpg)
So using php how can i fetch the data in this format ?

if I select **order a1**

[ORDER NO A1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxBnz.jpg)

or

if i selected order a2

Comment: There are no images and no code, how should we know what you did?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, your question has no mention of an attempt, and is vague at best.  This being said, I use this code for an intranet site:

```
function printTable(&$result) //mysqli result set
{
    /**  Set up Table and Headers **/
    $fieldinfo = $result->fetch_fields();
    echo '<table class="sqldump">' . "\n";
    echo '<tr class="header">' . "\n";
    foreach ($fieldinfo as $fieldval) {
        echo "<td>".$fieldval->name."</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";

    /** dump rows **/
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $column) {
            echo "<td>".$column."</td>\n";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";

    /**  gc  **/
    $result->free();
}
```

It will be up to you to format your own SQL queries, or edit your original post to show what specific difficulties you are struggling with.

It would still be a good idea to read the articles linked @Chaarlotte Dunois to avoid a similar response to your questions in the future